# How to avoid extra blank space on variable value when prompted in Windows cmd batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour with a Windows batch script when I want to read a value by prompting the user. Here is my script:

```dos
echo off

set VALUE=toto
set _VALUE=
set /p _VALUE=Enter the value or leave blank to accept default (%VALUE%):

if [%_VALUE%] NEQ [] ( set VALUE=%_VALUE% )

set _VALUE=

echo "%VALUE%"
```

If I keep the default, here is what I get, as expected:

```
...>myscript.cmd
Enter the value or leave blank to accept default (toto):
"toto"
```

But if I enter a new value, here is what I unexpectedly get:

```
...>myscript.cmd
Enter the value or leave blank to accept default (toto): titi
"titi "
```

- Why is there a blank space after `titi`, as seen in `"titi "`?
- What should be the syntax to simply get `"titi"`as expected?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Look at your `SET` command. I clearly see a space after the variable name and before the right parentheses: `( set VALUE=%_VALUE% )`. Best practice is to use this syntax: `if NOT "%_VALUE%"=="" set "VALUE=%_VALUE%"`

Comment: @Squashman Thanks, you're right! From my C++/C/etc background I assumed `VALUE` was set to _VALUE value but actually I understand that it is set to what is on the right side of the `=` sign... ;-)

Comment: Would also like to add that you don't need two variables to do what you are doing. You can just use the variable `value` with the `SET /P` command.  If they hit enter at the input prompt, the value will still be set to the default.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! I'll do that.

Comment: @dom_beau I recommend reading also my answer on [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564) if you want to make your batch file fail safe on accidentally or intentionally wrong user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your code, you can do this as a best practice.

```
@echo off

set VALUE=toto
set _VALUE=
set /p _VALUE=Enter the value or leave blank to accept default (%VALUE%):

if NOT "%_VALUE%"=="" set "VALUE=%_VALUE%"

set _VALUE=

echo "%VALUE%"
```

But all you really need to do is this.

```
set "VALUE=toto"
set /p VALUE=Enter the value or leave blank to accept default (%VALUE%):
echo %value%
```